# How can I assign a custom factor depending on another column?

Tags: r

I have data like this:

```
k <- data.frame(v=c(1:4),
                days=c("m", "m", "s", "m"),
                weekend=c(F, F, T, F)
     )
```

Lets say `m` is monday and `s` is saturday, so `s` rows are weekends.

How can I create a factor variable `weekendfactor` such that

```
> k
  v days   end weekendfactor
1 1    m FALSE       Weekday
2 2    m FALSE       Weekday
3 3    s  TRUE       Weekend
4 4    m FALSE       Weekday
```

I guess it somehow involves the `gl` function but I cant get my head around it (my mind is working in `if` statements).

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
library("car")
recode(k$days, "'m'='Weekday';'s'='Weekend'")
```

Result:

```
> k
  v days weekend weekendFactor
1 1    m   FALSE       Weekday
2 2    m   FALSE       Weekday
3 3    s    TRUE       Weekend
4 4    m   FALSE       Weekday
```

Since you already have your `weekend` column, you could also do:

```
ifelse(k$weekend, "Weekend", "Weekday")
```

To produce the same result (except that it will be "character" not "factor" class).

Comment: And casting to `factor` isn't a problem. Thanksè!

Answer (score 2):

Another way (as I hate `ifelse`) will be

```
c("Weekday", "Weekend")[k$weekend + 1]
# [1] "Weekday" "Weekday" "Weekend" "Weekday"
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is going on with your `[k$weekend + 1]` part? Looks like a really compact solution, but the syntax is quite abstract.

Comment: `k$weekend` is logical vector of `T` and `F`, thus I can't use it in order to index from `c("Weekday", "Weekend")`. If you'll convert it to `numeric` class (i.e., `as.numeric(k$weekend)`), you will see that it will turn `F` to `0` and `T` to `1`. `0` isn't a valid index in R, so by adding `1` this vector will become a vector of `1`s and `2`, this way I will be able to index from `c("Weekday", "Weekend")`.

Answer (score 1):

Or,

```
as.character(factor(k$days, labels=c("Weekday", "Weekend")))
#[1] "Weekday" "Weekday" "Weekend" "Weekday"
```